# Picasso crashed with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, picasso

I have been using Picasso for quite a while now.  I have encountered a weird problem today.

I simply loaded an image url to an imageview with this code,

```
Picasso.with(_context)
.load(groupDeatils.getThumbnail()).transform(new CircleTransform())
.into(group_pic);
```

This is my gradle build,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.km.contribill"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.shamanland:fab:0.0.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile project(':library')
}
```

After building the project when I run it and go to the page I am getting this error,

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Utils

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What other libs do you use ?

Comment: Add this line in gradle => compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) & try

Comment: @somerandomusername that is a default line in every gradle file in android studio...

Comment: @SuhasB that line is already added...do u want me to add it in reverse order..

Comment: @Proloy so you don't have any more *.jar under libs directory? Or sources from other libraries?

Comment: @somerandomusername yes i have, three .jar libraries gson, httpclient, httpcore

Comment: remove proguard from gradle and check once.

Comment: Seems like this is not a picasso issue...i have to add this 2 lines to my gradle and it started working again, dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries = false
    }